# Better way to structure a series of df manipulations in your class

Tags: python, pandas, oop, dataframe, functional-programming

How do you better **structure the code** in your class so that your class returns the `df` that you want, but you don't have a main method which calls a lot of other methods in sequential order. I find that in a lot of situations I arrive at this structure and it seems bad. I have a `df` that I just overwrite it with the result of other base functions (that I unit test) until I get what I want.

```
class A:
 def main(self):
   df = self.load_file_into_df()
   df = self.add_x_columns(df)
   df = self.calculate_y(df)
   df = self.calculate_consequence(df)
   ...
   return df

 def add_x_columns(df)
 def calculate_y(df)
 def calculate_consequence(df)
 ...

# now use it somewhere else
df = A().main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### pipe

One feature you may wish to utilize is [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html). This is considered "pandorable" because it facilitates operator chaining.

In my opinion, you should separate reading data into a dataframe from manipulating the dataframe. For example:

```
class A:
    def main(self):
        df = self.load_file_into_df()

        df = df.pipe(self.add_x_columns)\
               .pipe(self.calculate_y)\
               .pipe(self.calculate_consequence)

    return df
```

#### compose

Function composition is not native to Python, but the 3rd party [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library does offer this feature. This allows you to lazily define chained functions. Note the reversed order of operations, i.e. the last argument of `compose` is performed first.

```
from toolz import compose

class A:
    def main(self)
        df = self.load_file_into_df()

        transformer = compose(self.calculate_consequence,
                              self.calculate_y,
                              self.add_x_columns)

        df = df.pipe(transformer)

    return df
```

In my opinion, `compose` offers a flexible and adaptable solution. You can, for example, define any number of compositions and apply them selectively or repeatedly at various points in your workflow.